# How to change the height of div with the content of other div

Tags: javascript, css

I have two div in my website page one beside the other(one left and one right),I want to change the height of the left one with the content of the right one using javascript

I tried to have the dynamic height of the right div :

```
function getHeight() {
    var doc = document.getElementById('div.right');

    if (document.all) // ok I.E
    {
        H = doc.currentStyle.height;
    }
    else // ok FF
    {
        H = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(doc, null).height;
    }
}​
```

But I stopped here because I don't know how to pass the javascript variable to my page of style CSS,I mean I dont know how to apply this value in the other div(left div) in the same page automatically.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help people I found a great code to change the height of two div autoamtically using a little of Jquery :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
    var lh = $('#div.right').height();
     var rh = $('#div.left').height();
     if (lh >= rh){
    //alert('left : ' + lh);
    $('#div.left').height(lh);
    } else {
    //alert('right : ' + rh);
    $('#div.right').height(rh);
    };
    });
    </script>
```

It's works for all navigators.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
document.getElementById('div.left').style.height = H;
```

Edit

1. AFAIK you cant modify an external stylesheet from javascript
2. Is the height of the div determined at the time the document is served, loaded or or any arbitrary time after the document has loaded?

The code I suggested above was to be used like this(I'm assuming your IE code is correct)

```
function getHeight() {
    var doc = document.getElementById('div.right');
    if (document.all) // ok I.E
    {
        H = doc.currentStyle.height;
    }
    else // ok FF
    {
        H = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(doc, null).height;
    }
    document.getElementById('div.left').style.height = H;//✔
}
```

Comment: really this code dosn't work and the left div still have the same height different to div right